# Non-deterministic* data in header/beginning of PNG files

Tags: data-structures, graphics, png, metadata, gimp

I noticed that PNG files created by Gimp from the same RPG data are identical except for the very beginning. This image shows a diff of otherwise identical PNG files created with Gimp:

[image]

What is this data which changes each time and how is it encoded? Are there tools to decode it? Can you learn something from this information, e.g. can you find out when a PNG file was (probably) created by this information?

I was under the impression that PNG files are created deterministically* and don't store meta data which isn't necessary to decode the image. (Obviously, the last part is not true, either, as Gimp writes its own name into the files but doesn't ask the user (which is does if you export something as a JPEG file).)

* I use the word "deterministic" here to refer to things and only such which are the same on each execution/export/whatever given the same input. I'd usually use the word "functional" (i.e. like a mathematical function) but I fear this could be misunderstood by people who don't know what "functional" means in mathematics. Obviously, this is different from the usage of this word in information theory.

Comment: You could use "`pngcheck -v file.png`" to get a more informative listing of the PNG chunks.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [PNG header definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Ancillary_chunks).

- `tIME` *stores the time that the image was last changed*, so for me it's the same as the timestamp of the file you create.
- `bKGD` *gives the default background color*. Possibly the bakcgournd color you are using in Gimp, or the color of the transparent pixels.
- `tEXT` with key `Comment` and value `Created with Gimp` is just the default comment. You can change the comment for the image in `Image>Properties` and you can set a default comment in `Edit>Preferences>Default Image`

When I export the same PNG twice, I only see a change in `tIME`. In fact I can't get a `bKGD` item, even when exporting a PNG with transparent pixels. Are you using any specific options when exporting?

Comment: I just took a time stamp (Unix time) (`1496679909`) and converted it to hexadecimal: `593585E5` I don't even see any occurrence of `59` in the diff (and I created the second image shortly before posting this question). How can I interpret the data in the diff to find the times the PNG images were created?

Comment: I did not choose any special options when exporting the image. I merely pressed Ctrl + Shift + E to export the images (not sure whether I always pressed the shift key), sometimes entered a file name, and hit Enter. Apart from a script which allows me to draw arrows and things I moved around in the docks, my Gimp installation and configuration is just the upt-to-date stock version of the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories on the official main servers. My Gimp version is 2.8.16 but I'm not sure whether Ubuntu ships Gimp with special settings or anything alike.

Comment: [More complete specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11tIME) (this is the first thing to come up when you enter *png format specification* on DuckDuckGo). Time is not stored as seconds from the Epoch, but as Y/M/D/H/M/S bytes.

Comment: Thank you! When I googled it, I only got results which weren't exactly helpful.